# ILifetimeScope.ResolveNamed ComponentNotRegisteredException

Tags: c#, autofac

I am passing an `ILifetimeScope` to a class `ctor` with the intent of resolving a registered type by its name and interface type. The name is stored in a database and can be one of 5 or 6 types. For example:

```
public interface ISomeInterface
{
    Task SomeTask();
}

public class TypeA : ISomeInterface
{
    public async Task SomeTask()
    {
        await Task.Yield();
    }
}

public class TypeB : ISomeInterface
{
    public async Task SomeTask()
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
    }
}

public class SomeExecutor()
{
    private readonly ILifetimeScope _scope;

    public SomeExecutor(ILifetimeScope scope)
    {
        _scope = scope;
    }

    public async Task RunAsync(string type)
    {
        var class = _scope.ResolveNamed<ISomeInterface>(type); // This throws the exception.
        await class.SomeTask();
    }
}

public static class Program()
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterType<SomeExecutor>();
        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(ISomeInterface).Assembly)
            .Where(x => typeof(ISomeInterface.IsAssignableFrom(x))
            .AsImplementedInterfaces()
            .AsSelf(); // Taken from Autofac docs.
        var container = builder.Build();
        var executor = container.Resolve<SomeExecutor>();
        executor.RunAsync("TypeA").Wait();
    }
}
```

The exception thrown is

> The requested service 'TypeA (ISomeInterface)' has not been registered. To avoid this exception, either register a component to provide the service, check for service registration using IsRegistered(), or use the ResolveOptional() method to resolve an optional dependency.

I did what was suggested by the error and checked `IsRegistered(typeof(ISomeInterface))` and `IsRegistered(typeof(TypeA))` and the result is `True` for both.

I have done some runtime debugging and verified that the type exists in `_scope.ComponentRegistry.Registrations`, however I noticed the scope of that particular type is `CurrentScopeLifetime` as opposed to some other types which are `RootScopeLifetime`. I'm not sure if this has any significance.

I have tried registering `ISomeInterface` in a few different ways, such as

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(ISomeInterface).Assembly)
    .Where(x => typeof(ISomeInterface.IsAssignableFrom(x))
    .AsSelf();

builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(ISomeInterface).Assembly)
    .Where(x => typeof(ISomeInterface.IsAssignableFrom(x))
    .As<ISomeInterface>();

builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(ISomeInterface).Assembly)
    .Where(x => typeof(ISomeInterface.IsAssignableFrom(x))
    .As<ISomeInterface>()
    .AsSelf();

builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(ISomeInterface).Assembly)
    .Where(x => typeof(ISomeInterface.IsAssignableFrom(x))
    .AsImplementedInterfaces()
    .AsSelf()
    .AssignableTo<ISomeInterface>();
```

And probably every other combination I could think of.

My question here is, what am I doing wrong that I am unable to resolve the type by name and interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the name, then it will work

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(ISomeInterface).Assembly)
    .Where(x => typeof(ISomeInterface).IsAssignableFrom(x))
    .AsImplementedInterfaces()
    .AsSelf().Named<ISomeInterface>(x => x.Name);
```

Or you could use the actual type instead of the name of the type

```
public class SomeExecutor
{
    private readonly ILifetimeScope _scope;

    public SomeExecutor(ILifetimeScope scope)
    {
        _scope = scope;
    }

    public async Task RunAsync<T>() where T:ISomeInterface
    {
        var tt = _scope.Resolve<T>(); 
        await  tt.SomeTask();
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterType<SomeExecutor>();
        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(ISomeInterface).Assembly)
            .Where(x => typeof(ISomeInterface).IsAssignableFrom(x))
            .AsImplementedInterfaces()
            .AsSelf();
        var container = builder.Build();
        var executor = container.Resolve<SomeExecutor>();
        executor.RunAsync<TypeA>().Wait();
    }
```

Comment: the `.Named<ISomeInterface>(x => x.Name)` does it. Unfortunately, I can't use a `<T>` parameter to the `RunAsync` method, because the type isn't yet known, it is queried from the DB inside that method.